# MustacheException$Context: No key, method or field with name 'description' on line

Tags: spring-restdocs

I'm trying to generate rest docs for my endpoint:

```java
webTestClient.patch()
             .uri(ENTITY_BY_ID, entityId)
             .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
             .header(AUTHORIZATION, accessToken)
             .bodyValue(body)
             .exchange()
             .expectStatus()
             .isOk()
             .expectBody()
             .consumeWith(document("Entity/PATCH_API", //
                                   pathParameters(parameterWithName("id").description("ID of the entity to patch")),
                                   requestFields(fieldWithPath("condition"),//
                                                 fieldWithPath("type").description("one of A, B, S"),
                                                 fieldWithPath("applyTo"),//
                                                 fieldWithPath("substituteWith"),//
                                                 fieldWithPath("priority"),//
                                                 fieldWithPath("comment"))));
```

But it throws the error:

```
org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.MustacheException$Context: No key, method or field with name 'description' on line 7

at org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Mustache$VariableSegment.execute(Mustache.java:789)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Template$1.execute(Template.java:131)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Template$1.execute(Template.java:124)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Template$Fragment.execute(Template.java:59)
at org.springframework.restdocs.templates.mustache.AsciidoctorTableCellContentLambda.execute(AsciidoctorTableCellContentLambda.java:36)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Mustache$SectionSegment.execute(Mustache.java:856)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Mustache$BlockSegment.executeSegs(Mustache.java:827)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Mustache$SectionSegment.execute(Mustache.java:848)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Template.executeSegs(Template.java:114)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Template.execute(Template.java:91)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Template.execute(Template.java:82)
at org.springframework.restdocs.templates.mustache.MustacheTemplate.render(MustacheTemplate.java:62)
at org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.TemplatedSnippet.document(TemplatedSnippet.java:82)
at org.springframework.restdocs.generate.RestDocumentationGenerator.handle(RestDocumentationGenerator.java:191)
at org.springframework.restdocs.webtestclient.WebTestClientRestDocumentation.lambda$document$0(WebTestClientRestDocumentation.java:77)
at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultBodyContentSpec.lambda$consumeWith$3(DefaultWebTestClient.java:564)
at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.ExchangeResult.assertWithDiagnostics(ExchangeResult.java:206)
at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultBodyContentSpec.consumeWith(DefaultWebTestClient.java:564)
at org.my.routers.EntityRouterTest$PATCH_API.patch_success(EntityRouterTest.java:319)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue. All `fieldWithPath` should have a description:

```java
.consumeWith(document("Entity/PATCH_API", //
                      pathParameters(parameterWithName("id").description("ID of the entity to patch")),
                      requestFields(fieldWithPath("condition").description("JS boolean condition"),//
                                    fieldWithPath("type").description("one of A, B, C"),
                                    fieldWithPath("applyTo").description("some descr"),//
                                    fieldWithPath("substituteWith").description("some descr"),//
                                    fieldWithPath("priority").description("int value"),//
                                    fieldWithPath("comment").description("any text"))));
```

Comment: You may be interested in [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/678) that hopes to improve the error message so that the problem's easier to identify.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are trying to use the description as a mean to display an example value, ensure that it is not null, if it is, it will throw this error too.
example:

```
class Customer {
 private final String name;
 private final String id;

 public Customer(String name, String id){
   this.name = name;
   this.id = id;
  }

}

final Customer = new Customer("test name", null);

....

 fieldWithPath("id")
                    .description(customer.getId())
                    .type(String.class),
```

such a field would cause the error